# How do i continuously read data that send by the bluetooth device?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a react-native bluetooth application using **react-native-ble-plx** npm package. From that application we can scan for devices and connect with my bluetooth device and that device continuesly send data to the application in that scenario how do i read data continuously sends from the connected bluetooth device in the app.

react-native-ble-plx : https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

Documentation : https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/

Thanks in advance

Comment: A side question: Why do you use BLE when sending data continuously? BLE is optimized for energy and not very useful when data is sent permanently.

Comment: But if you have to use BLE: How is the data sent by the device? Notifications? In this case, you have to configure the CCCD of the data characteristic to receive the notifications on the app.